# Semantic UI - Adding Logic Around Search Box

Tags: javascript, jquery, semantic-ui

I'm trying to add some logic around a search box according to a user selected dropdown box.

Search Box:

```
<div class="ui search">
    <div class="ui left loading icon input">
        <input class="prompt" type="text" placeholder="Search Youtube" value="">
        <i class="icon"></i>
    </div>
</div>
```

A dropdown:

```
<div class="ui selection dropdown">
    <input name="type" type="hidden" value="">
    <i class="dropdown icon"></i>
    <div class="default text">Search Type</div>
    <div class="menu">
        <div class="item" data-value="1">Channel ID</div>
        <div class="item" data-value="0">User Name</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

For example, if user selects B on the dropdown box, my query command will query `B={some value}`, and `A=Blank`. If user selects A on the dropdown box, then `B=Blank`, and `A={some value}`.

This is what I've tried to do, but I'm not sure how to wrap around the `$('.ui.search')` function with logic. Or is it possible to have multiple queries, for example `q={id}?results={count}` and keep this string externally, but when the user types on the search, I would like to modify the a `var` that keeps the URL variable, and insert it into the apiSetting's url field.

```
$('.ui.search')
    .search
    (
        {
            apiSettings: {
                onResponse: function (Response) {
                    console.log("Hellop");
                    console.log($('.ui.dropdown').dropdown('get value'));

                },
                url: 'http://192.168.219.130:8888/'
            },
        }
    )
$('.ui.dropdown').dropdown({});
```

Greatly appreciate it if someone can point me to the right direction on how this could be handled in Semantic UI framework.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll want to modify your API request URL and settings just before the API request is sent. This can be done with the `beforeSend` callback of the `apiSettings` object.

Your search initialization would look something like this:

```
$('.ui.search')
    .search
    ({
        apiSettings: {
            onBeforeSend: function(settings) {
                // Depending on your logic, modify your URL here
                settings.url = 'http://192.168.219.130:8888/';

                return settings;                    
            },

            onResponse: function (Response) {
                console.log("Hellop");
                console.log($('.ui.dropdown').dropdown('get value'));

            },
            url: 'http://192.168.219.130:8888/'
        },
    })
```

Some more information can be found on the [semantic UI API usage page](http://semantic-ui.com/behaviors/api.html#/usage).

Comment: Thanks, will try this asap.

Comment: This works, also in my version of semantic, it's called beforeSend, Thanks!